# Ruby gems not available - mac, probably PATH issue

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

### The Problem

I can't install ruby gems properly, here's what I get trying to install and run chef:

```
$ gem install chef && chef
Successfully installed chef-11.6.0
Parsing documentation for chef-11.6.0
1 gem installed
bash: chef: command not found
```

My path is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/mcarey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/mcarey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/mcarey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/mcarey/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mcarey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems
```

### Background/History

It was all working fine until I accidentally (long story short) created a tilde (~) directory and then tried to remove it with 'rm -R ~', this of course started deleting my home directory but once it hit the first protected file it asked for permission and I cancelled it.  My old ~/.bash_profile was removed but I'm not sure what else went.

Any thoughts? Any extra info needed?

Comment: Why do you think it shoud have `bower` executable file? It doesn't have one as I can see in it's repository https://github.com/spagalloco/bower

Comment: From the readme, it looks like a suitable command line might be `rails generate bower:install`, provided your goal is to add `bower` support to a new Rails project. Otherwise, you don't need to run anything, just `require 'bower'` in your project

Comment: Why do you think it should have bower executable file?
Only because I thought I had one before, there are some gems which i know I want executables for (e.g. less, sass) I'll see if Bower was a bad example.

Comment: "just require 'bower' in your project" - what project? ;) I'm not running a rails project.  I work on all sorts of different projects, some are rails, some aren't and I've got (or at least had) a load of tools installed for that before this stupid mistake.

Comment: OK, it looks like Bower's a bad example - the readme says to install through npm, not gem.  I'll check a different example and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Just for clarity I've updated the example from bower to chef (because I know chef uses a command-line tool).

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your ~/.bash_profile file, I think that Gems will work until you fix your path in this new file. So :

1. Be sure that you have recreated your ~/.bash_profile file in your home folder 
   (terminal command : `mate ~/.profile`)
2. Check if this line exists `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`
3. if this line does not exist, add this in your file
4. save the file
5. To check if the file is correct input `. ~/.profile` in the terminal

I guess your probleme is only a path problem but if you face with another problem here is a link [where to find more info](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard)

But if your path is correct you can try to use your gem this way:

1. Go to your application root folder
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec bower`

=> MAYBE THIS CAN HELP : Checking documentation in github and google, ifound [this article](http://dev.af83.com/2013/01/02/managing-rails-assets-with-bower.html)
there is a possibility to use the bower-rails gem.

in your Gemfile:

```
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.4.4"
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: It should be `bundle exec ...` not `exec bundle ...` :)

Comment: Hey, I already had /usr/local/bin in my path but I've added sbin (logically bower would've been bin rather than sbin anyway).  Still broken with the same symptoms.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev you are right its `bundle exec' --- sorrry